# Why does a ScheduledExecutorService not run a task again after an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, error-handling, threadpool

For executing periodical tasks, I looked at [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) (with a single thread) and decided to use the latter, because in the [`reference for Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29), it says:

> Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.

My plan was to use this as a safeguard against uncaught exceptions in a watchdog piece of code that I want to monitor other operations. I wanted to make sure and wrote the test below, which promptly failed. It seems I was making wrong assumptions, or is something wrong about my test?

Here's the code:

```
@Test
public void testTimer() {
    final AtomicInteger cTries = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final AtomicInteger cSuccesses = new AtomicInteger(0);

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            cTries.incrementAndGet();
            if (true) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            cSuccesses.incrementAndGet();
        }
    };

    /*
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 500);
     */
    ScheduledExecutorService exe = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exe.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            wait(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
    exe.shutdown();
    /*
    t.purge();
     */
    Assert.assertEquals(cSuccesses.get(), 0);
    Assert.assertTrue(cTries.get() > 1, String.format("%d is not greater than 1. :(", cTries.get()));
}
```

Comment: I know, I can wrap a catch(Throwable) around stuff, but my plan was to somehow protect me from myself.

Comment: it would be problematic for framework code like this to assume it can safely restart a failed job - the fact that it failed with an exception means that the data might have been left in any sort of state, and potentially it would be unsafe to restart the job.

Comment: The quote about a starting a new thread is to allow other jobs to continue to run, even if one fails

Comment: @mattb Suppressing subsequent executions might be the right thing to do, but I would still expect it to log the uncaught exception via the `ThreadFactory`s `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. There is no reason to silently ignore the errors. The `ExecutorService` can handle when threads die, so at the very least, do any cleanup that the repeater needs to do, then re-throw the exception and let the thread's handler log it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Once a repeating task has thrown an uncaught exception it is assumed to have died or be in an error state.  It is a bit of a gotcha that it also fails silently unless you examine the Future to get the Error/Exception.

You have to catch Exceptions if you don't want to kill the repeating task.

---

*As matt b points out in the comment above,*

> it would be problematic for framework code like this to assume it can safely restart a failed job - the fact that it failed with an exception means that the data might have been left in any sort of state, and potentially it would be unsafe to restart the job.

Comment: Is this still applicable? In Spring boot 1.5.3 the default error handler for repeating tasks is [LOG_AND_SUPRESS_ERROR_HANDLER](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/TaskUtils.html#LOG_AND_SUPPRESS_ERROR_HANDLER) which will not remove @Scheduled from the execution queue.

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea to program the code to ignore the exceptions and restart automatically, but can I program a RESTful service that I can use to restart the scheduler once I fix the issue manually?

Comment: @jDub9 you can. There is no problem creating a new ExecutorService or a new task when you are ready to run again.

Answer (score 9):

*matt b* has given the reason.

> it would be problematic for framework code like this to assume it can
> safely restart a failed job - the fact that it failed with an
> exception means that the data might have been left in any sort of
> state, and potentially it would be unsafe to restart the job.

It should be noted that is written in the documentation of  [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent
> executions are suppressed.

And as  *Michael Krusse* says, the point about creating a new thread is to allow other tasks to continue running.