# How to check whether @Schedule annotation (Spring 3.1) cron job is running.

Tags: java, spring, cron

In my application I have one cron job which connects to a FTP server and transfer files, a very simple functionality and it is configured using spring @Schedule annotation with cron expression as a parameter.
It was running fine for few months and then suddenly it stopped, got the connectException.
May be the FTP server was down or something happened which causes the cron thread to stop.
I looked (google)  for the reasons but didnt get any ( Nothing much in the logs also - Just the exception name ).It may be a one time thing :)

my question is that can I put some check or watcher on the @Schedule cron job to know whether it is running or not ?

Sorry for my bad explanation/english

Thanks

Comment: You can always send a mail to a given address on a job failure -- with the stacktrace in it

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, do you have some example or can you point me to right document about configuring email on @Schedule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my question is that can I put some check or watcher on the @Schedule
>   cron job to know whether it is running or not ?

Basically, you can't.

When you use `@Scheduled`, Spring uses a `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to register the tasks you specify (annotated methods). It registers them with a `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`. The `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is an `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshEvent>`. When it receives the `ContextRefreshEvent` from the `ApplicationContext`, it schedules the tasks registered in the `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`.

During this step, these tasks are scheduled with a `TaskScheduler` which typically wraps a `ScheduledExecutorService`. [If an exception is uncaught in a submitted task, then the task is removed from the `ScheduledExecutorService` queue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494557/why-does-a-scheduledexecutorservice-not-run-a-task-again-after-an-exception-is-t)

**The `TaskScheduler` class does not provide a public API to retrieve the scheduled tasks**, ie. the `ScheduledFuture` objects. So you can't use it to find out if your tasks are running or not.

And you probably shouldn't. Develop your tasks, your `@Scheduled` methods, to be able to withstand an exception being thrown. Some times, obviously, that's not possible. With a network error, for example, you would probably have to restart your application. Without knowing anything else about your application, I would say more logging is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will maintain the cron context in DB means last execution time, next execution time. And another service will check that time with current time and hopefully I will know that Thread is running or not.

Comment: I might note that a reasonable reason why being able to determine this could be to enable a system administrator visibility of tasks that could be presently running that it's best to avoid shutting down the service, such as a general ledger posting routine.