# Spring @Scheduled: How to detect wheter a method was called as a job?

Tags: spring, spring-scheduled

Spring has the `@Scheduled` annotation which makes a method being called as a scheduled job.

Is there supported way to recognize within the method whether it was called by this scheduling, or directly from other code?

By `supported` I mean that it can't be some hack like checking the call stack, or relying on some side effect like HTTP request somewhere in the context.

Comment: No that's not possible

Comment: More information is provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892072/how-to-check-whether-schedule-annotation-spring-3-1-cron-job-is-running

Answer (score 0):

As noted, it's not possible.  Just a quick thought on your design, if you want to know when it's called from the scheduler, extract a method that's scheduled and calls your method with an added parameter like `fromScheduler`.

Something like this:

```
@Scheduled
public void callAnotherMethod() {
   methodYouWantToCall(true);
}

public void methodYouWantToCall(boolean fromScheduler) {
   if (fromScheduler) {
      log.debug("called from scheduler");
   } else {
      log.debug("non from scheduler");
   }
}
```

It's hairy, but it would avoid looking at the stack trace.  Personally, I don't see any reason that you couldn't just use the stack trace.

```
boolean scheduled = Arrays.stream(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace())
    .anyMatch(stackTraceElement -> stackTraceElement.getClassName().contains(
        ScheduledMethodRunnable.class.getName()));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what we have, and since we have many jobs, I wanted to get rid of these methods...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using aspects? Something like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogInterceptor {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogInterceptor.class);

    @Before("execution(public * my.package.name.schedulers..*.*(..))")
    public void logBeforeAllSchedulers(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        String className = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getSimpleName();
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

        log.debug("Executing: [{}]", "class: " + className + ", method: " + methodName + ", arguments: " + Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```